# Redshift: Nested Loop Join in the query plan

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-optimization

I have my fact table `t_session` which looks simplified like this:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+
| start_hm   | end_hm   | device_id   |
|------------+----------+-------------|
| 0          | 10       | 111         |
| 2          | 10       | 112         |
| 12         | 20       | 113         |
| 60         | 90       | 111         |
| 60         | 90       | 112         |
```

I also have my dimension table `dim_time`, which contains 1440 records with hours 0-23 and minutes 0-59 for every hour. So it contains all combination of hour-minute for a day. `tk` is a range of numbers 0-1439

```
+------+--------+----------+
| tk   | hour   | minute   |
|------+--------+----------|
| 0    | 0      | 0        |
| 1    | 0      | 1        |
| 2    | 0      | 2        |
............................
| 60   | 1      | 0        |
| 61   | 1      | 1        |
| 62   | 1      | 2        |
............................
| 120  | 2      | 0        |
| 121  | 2      | 1        |
| 122  | 2      | 2        |
............................
```

I want to count the number of active device_id for every minute. In real application there is another table `dim_date` and half a dozen other relations, but let's keep it simple for this question.

The device is active in time slot between `start_hm` and `end_hm`. Both `start_hm` and `end_hm` have values between 0 and 1439.

```
select count(distinct device_id)
from t_session
join dim_time on tk between start_hm and end_hm
group by tk
order by tk;
```

This query executes slow like hell. When I look on the execution plan it complains about the Nested loop.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| XN Limit  (cost=1000002000820.94..1000002000820.97 rows=10 width=8)                                                            |
|   ->  XN Merge  (cost=1000002000820.94..1000002000821.44 rows=200 width=8)                                                     |
|         Merge Key: tk                                                                                                          |
|         ->  XN Network  (cost=1000002000820.94..1000002000821.44 rows=200 width=8)                                             |
|               Send to leader                                                                                                   |
|               ->  XN Sort  (cost=1000002000820.94..1000002000821.44 rows=200 width=8)                                          |
|                     Sort Key: tk                                                                                               |
|                     ->  XN HashAggregate  (cost=2000812.80..2000813.30 rows=200 width=8)                                       |
|                           ->  XN Subquery Scan volt_dt_0  (cost=2000764.80..2000796.80 rows=3200 width=8)                      |
|                                 ->  XN HashAggregate  (cost=2000764.80..2000764.80 rows=3200 width=8)                          |
|                                       ->  XN Nested Loop DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=0.00..2000748.80 rows=3200 width=8)             |
|                                             Join Filter: (("outer".tk <= "inner".end_hm) AND ("outer".tk >= "inner".start_hm)) |
|                                             ->  XN Seq Scan on dim_time  (cost=0.00..28.80 rows=2880 width=4)                  |
|                                             ->  XN Seq Scan on t_session  (cost=0.00..0.10 rows=10 width=12)                   |
| ----- Nested Loop Join in the query plan - review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products -----                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I understand where the nested loop comes from. It needs to loop over `dim_time` for every record in `t_session`.

Is it possible to modify my query to avoid the nested loop and improve the performance?

UPDATE: The same query is running blazingly fast on Postgres and the execution plan does not have Cartesian product.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                   |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Limit  (cost=85822.07..85839.17 rows=10 width=12)                                                            |
|   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=85822.07..88284.47 rows=1440 width=12)                                           |
|         Group Key: dim_time.tk                                                                               |
|         ->  Sort  (cost=85822.07..86638.07 rows=326400 width=8)                                              |
|               Sort Key: dim_time.tk                                                                          |
|               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..51467.40 rows=326400 width=8)                                     |
|                     Join Filter: ((dim_time.tk >= t_session.start_hm) AND (dim_time.tk <= t_session.end_hm)) |
|                     ->  Seq Scan on t_session  (cost=0.00..30.40 rows=2040 width=12)                         |
|                     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=1440 width=4)                                    |
|                           ->  Seq Scan on dim_time  (cost=0.00..25.40 rows=1440 width=4)                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

UPDATE2:

The `t_session` table has `device_id` column as DISTKEY and `start_date` column (not shown in the simplified example) as the SORTKEY: sessions are naturally sorted by the `start_date`.

The `dim_time` table has `tk` as the SORTKEY and DISTSTYLE ALL.

The execution time for 40000 sessions per day is 5-6 minutes on Redshift. And a couple of seconds on Postgres.

There are two dc2.large nodes on Redshift cluster

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve from this query? The purpose of the `dim_time` table is unclear. Are you simply wanting to count the number of minutes that each device was active? Can you state state the requirements in words?

Comment: @John Rotenstein I added some info to my question. I need to count the number of active devices for every minute (and every date and with some other conditions but let's keep it simple here).

Comment: Please doe not tag Redshift questions with `postgresql`. Although they share some common roots, especially the query optimizers are very different.

Comment: First, the `SORT BY` is not needed and can be removed. Second, I wonder if the performance can be improved by using `DISTKEY device_id` to keep all records related to one device on the same slice? Possibly also `SORTKEY device_id` to make it more efficient, but I'm not sure about that one. How many nodes are in your cluster? If there are multiple nodes, using `DISTKEY ALL` on `tk` might give a slight improvement, hopefully avoiding the `DS_BCAST_INNER`. What are the actual execution times in Redshift and PostgreSQL?

Comment: @John Rotenstein  Please see my UPDATE2